# Unregister callbacks for Facebook Login Button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Newest Facebook SDK for Android in versions 4.17.0 and 4.18.0 is causing memory leak for Logging Implementation. There is a way to register callbacks, but there should also be way to unregister them in for example *onDestroy()* method. Do you know how to unregister callbacks for Facebook **LoginButton** implementation?

I'm registering facebook callbacks in *onCreate()* in this way:

```
    mCallbackManger = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mFacebookLoginBtn.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    mFacebookLoginBtn.registerCallback(mCallbackManger, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Timber.d("Facebook login success %s", loginResult.toString());
            showProgressDialog();
            getPresenter().loginWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Timber.d("Facebook login cancel");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Timber.d("Facebook login error %s", error.toString());

        }
    });
```

I forgot to mention that the button was not visible on screen, but I was passing to it onclick event from my custom button. As it occurred the cause of the problem was that weird call. The final solution was removing of *mFacebookLoginBtn* and calling in on custom button onClick event:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Collections.singletonList("public_profile"));
```

Comment: The Facebook SDK has a method `unregisterCallback(final CallbackManager callbackManager)`. Have you tried that out?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this kind of memory leak is not to use (inner) anonymous class. And take advantage of `WeakReference`.

```
// Fragment or whatever your class is...
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public  [...] {
        mCallbackManger = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mFacebookLoginBtn.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
        mFacebookLoginBtn.registerCallback(mCallbackManger, new MyFragment.FBCallback(this));
    }

    // New static class (not inner)
    static class FBCallback implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        private WeakReference<MyFragment> fragmentRef;

        public FBCallback(MyFragment fragment) {
            fragmentRef = new WeakReference<>(fragment)
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Timber.d("Facebook login success %s", loginResult.toString());

            MyFragment fragment = fragmentRef.get()
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.showProgressDialog();
                fragment.getPresenter().loginWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Timber.d("Facebook login cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Timber.d("Facebook login error %s", error.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it have occurred this didn't solve the problem that I had. But it's good practice and I like it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for unregister or logout facebook callback.
please put this code where logout button is there.

```
try {
      if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
       }
 } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
 }
```